# Is there a way to use JFace Components (like ComboViewer) in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, swt, jface

currently i'm developing my UIs with SWT / JFace. I like some of the widgets of JFace like ComboViewer, ListViewer, they help me a lot to populate data, filter data and update data to the lists and combo boxes.

But in lack of some additons (like a "nicer" autocomplete, or using a L&F, not platform independed without serving a lot of librarys or building a HUGE all in one Jar) i would like to use Swing.

Is it possible to use there widgets in Swing? And do you think I have any advantages using swt / jface? (I'm not developing eclipse addons, just for daily use)

Comment: Keep in mind that you will always have to include the appropriate SWT library if you use SWT components. Even if *most* of the application was Swing.

Comment: @Baz: You're right :D Didn't thought about that. But there is no way to use the comboviewer etc.?